# How to modify my script to loop over multiple calendars instead of just one

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

I use this script in a google sheet to search a named calendar for events where the title mentions a specific customer name (tracking project dates mostly).  This is fine for me to search one calendar, but I'd like to search a group of calendars at once and get all the events from them and then print all the results to the google sheet.  I feel like this is trivial, but I'm at a loss of how to properly iterate over the array with the getEvent function

Edit:  I was able to figure it out and the script below is quite useful to me for searching many calendars to find all events where a string is matched in that event.  The script is run from a menu item added to the sheets ui, and a popup box is shown for the user to pass on the search string. The search checks in the entire event object for the string and you can pass in match, multi-match, negation, etc.

Here is the working code:

```
// add menu option for 
function onOpen () {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
ui.createMenu('Custom Actions')
  .addItem('New Calendar Search', 'main')
  .addToUi()
}

function main(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.clearContents();
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,5);
range.setValues(header);
// var mycals is an array of google calendar id's; for gsuite, this is the email address of the user which calendar you will be viewing.
var mycals = ['email1@myemail.com','email2@myemail.com','email3@myemail.com']

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
var response = ui.prompt('Enter your search string:')
var custname = response.getResponseText()
for (var j=0;j<mycals.length;j++) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycals[j]);
  // error handling in case you don't have access to any specified calendar
  if (!cal) { continue; }
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 1, 2018 00:00:00 EST"), new Date("December 31, 2018 23:59:59 EST"), {search: custname});
  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
    var row = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    var details=[[events[i].getOriginalCalendarId(),events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime()]];
    var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
    range.setValues(details);
  }
sheet.sort(4)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just get an error "TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of null. (line 8, file "Code")" no matter how I mess around with this code.

Instead of

```
var mycal = "my.email@myworkdomain.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
```

try

```
var cal = CalendarApp.defaulCalendar();
```

NOTES: It's not possible to use `CalendarApp.getCalendarById(Id)` to access the default calendar of other users if they didn't shared it with the effective user.

Reference

- [defaultCalendar()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getdefaultcalendar)

Comment: I've edited my question as I was able to figure it out today.  The calendars I am searching are all shared to me, so getCalendarById() works great for me.  I was just having some trouble with the loop and getting the data into the spreadsheet cleanly, but its working great now.